# Preg replace with array of patterns not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

Why would this code

```
 $my_replacements = array("my dog", "doga");
 $my_string = "doga my dog test";
 $my_patterns = array_map(function($my_text) { return "/(^|[\n\r\f\t \.\,])" . trim($my_text) . "([\n\r\f\t \.\,]|$)/iu"; }, $my_replacements);
 $replaced_string = preg_replace($my_patterns, '', $my_string);
 echo $replaced_string;
```

return `dogatest` instead of `test`?

but if my_string is changed to `"my dog doga test"`, it replaces correctly both elements in my_replacements?

What I want to accomplish is that, given a string, find all the strings that are in $my_replacements and delete them from the string.  Taking into account the /u modifier and /i modifier or a preg_replace, because it can happen that the substring is in uppercase, and it has to be deleted either way.

Comment: could you please do a print_r of the `my_patterns` array? Also what value does `$my_text` has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your replacements are transformed to the following regexps:

```
/(^|[\n\r\f\t \.\,])my dog([\n\r\f\t \.\,]|$)/iu
/(^|[\n\r\f\t \.\,])doga([\n\r\f\t \.\,]|$)/iu
```

After the first regex is applied to the source string `"my dog doga test"` - it cuts off the `dog doga` **with spaces around it**. So you get `dogatest`.

And after that the second regex cannot match anything, because it expects the `doga` to be enclosed by beginning or the end of the string, a space or punctuation. But in your case it's in the beginning of the string (`true`) but there is no a space, punctuation or end of the string after (`false`).

That's why the second regex doesn't modify the string and you get `dogatest` as a final result.

Straightforward solution without regexes:

```
 $my_replacements = array("my dog", "doga");
 $my_string = "doga my dog test";
 $replaced_string = str_replace($my_replacements, '', $my_string);
 echo $replaced_string;
```

The kind [@Asad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726343/asad) created a codepad demo of the script: http://codepad.org/ywbZR1i8

Comment: Oh! Well, how could I solve that? Why are my replacements transformed to that? I basically want to find any words that are in my replacements inside my string...

Comment: @Hommer Smith: because **YOU** do that with this code - `$my_patterns = array_map(function($my_text) { return "/(^|[\n\r\f\t \.\,])" . trim($my_text) . "([\n\r\f\t \.\,]|$)/iu"; }, $my_replacements);`

Comment: zerkms, I am trying to find a solution. What would be a good approach so I can try to find all the replacements in my array that are inside the string?

Comment: @Hommer Smith: how about `str_replace`? Why do you need regexes at first?

Comment: zerkms because I want to be able to find the pattern if there are "," "." or \n\f\t and also because it has to be case unsensitive...

Comment: @Hommer Smith: "I want to be able to find the pattern if there are" --- to find and to do what? PS: there is `str_ireplace()`, it is case insensitive.

Comment: I want to be able to delete those appearances, or in other words clean the string of those strings that are in my_replacements.

Comment: @HommerSmith Use the approach zerkms has provided in his answer to clean the string of words that are undesired.

Comment: @Hommer Smith: any my `str_replace` based answer does that. Well, now it looks like wasting of my time. Please explain **IN DETAILS** of what you need to achieve, guessing is not a right way to answer.

Comment: @HommerSmith Here is a demonstration, in case you want to see it working http://codepad.org/ywbZR1i8

Comment: @Hommer Smith: change to `str_ireplace` (as I **already** mentioned before) and you would get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason of why you don't use str_replace?
If yes, you can use
`$my_replacements = array("doga", "my dog");`
instead of
`$my_replacements = array("my dog", "doga");`

Reason: after "doga" is replaced with '' in your string, this becomes "dogatest". So, doga with spaces (as you defined the regular exp) is not there. You could also make the replace with " " instead of '',
`$replaced_string = preg_replace($my_patterns, ' ', $my_string);`
And then trim and replace all multiple spaces with one space (a simple recursive replace).